# facebook API [login/Security]

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, authentication, passwords

I'm developing a website where users can create an account with email + password or just via login with facebook (in one click).
I want to give them to possibility to disable their account but before they must enter their password.
For the first users ( who create an account with email + password ) it is ok.

But for others (facebook users) I can't ask them for password because they are logged via facebook.
does anyone have an idea to solve this?
thanks

Comment: You can force Facebook users to re-enter their Facebook password, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. I will try it